# Questions about vue-rouer addRoutes

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router, { initLayout } from './router'
import store from './store'

require('../mock/index')

Vue.config.productionTip = false
initLayout()
new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

router.js

```
export async function initLayout () {
  await axios.get('http://localhost/layout').then((res) => {
    let path = '@'  +  res.data[0].component
    // res.data[0].component = () => import(path)
    res.data[0].component = Promise.resolve(import(path))
    router.addRoutes([...res.data])
  })
}
```

mock.js

```
export default Mock.mock('http://localhost/layout', [{
  path: '/about',
  name: 'About',
  // route level code-splitting
  // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
  // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
  component: '/views/About.vue'
}])
```

Why the browser prompts Cannot find module '@/views/About.vue'

I want axios to request the back-end to obtain the component and the corresponding address of the component, and then the front-end imports the component by obtaining the address. Finally, addRoutes will be processed, but the browser prompts that it cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
handle layout logic at client side, don't server here, that's a really a bad idea.

vue bundler serves transpiled js files, its directory structure looks like same as the dist folder which you get on building vue app for production

there will be no views or blah blah folders single /js folder that contains all the bundles.
and you are sending a path from server that doesn't work. because of this. and one more thing is modules filename changes.

hope you get this.

say you sending "./view/about.vue"
vue metro server don't know about this. it knows only /js/somehash.js